# Two file numeric comparison in awk

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to compare the contents of two files, both of which are just a single column of numbers, i.e.

File1:

> 1.2
>   2.6
>   3.4
>   4.7
>   5.3

File2:

> 5.1
>   4.8
>   3.2
>   2.5
>   1.6

The output should just be the number of lines in file1 that are greater than the corresponding line in file2; so in this case it'd just be

> 3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

awk single process can do that job:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}a[FNR]>$0{i++}END{print i}' file1 file2
```

outputs:

```
3
```

**EDIT**

by reading JonathanLeffler and steveha's comments, I would add another solution, to avoid to save a monster file into memory. still single awk process:

```
 awk '{getline x < "file2"}$0>x{i++}END{print i}' file1
```

outputs:

```
3
```

Comment: This reads all of `file1` into memory.  For some inputs this may not be practical.

Comment: @steveha I agree with you. but I don't see any notice/description in OP's question, saying that he was facing monster files. in practice, this one liner (one file in array, check the other file) is relatively often used.  There always is way with single awk to handle this kind of problem. I would update the answer, with reading two files in parallel

Comment: Thanks so much for the help; I completely forgot to consider that file size may be an issue in the long run, but as it stands the files I'm working with are only on the order of megabytes.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `paste` followed by `awk`

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '$1>$2 {i++} END {print i}'
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: This is a clean implementation of the obvious solution to the problem as described.  Further, it has the advantage that if the files are gigabytes in size, it does not store the whole of file 1 in (`awk`'s) memory, so it can process gargantuan files if need be. The downside is the cost of moving all the data through a pipe.

Comment: I suggest adding `0` to each of `$1` and `$2` to coerce them to numbers; otherwise you may have a surprising result on some inputs.  I just tested and AWK does seem to do the right thing as long as the inputs work as numbers, but the expression `100.3 < "abc"` evaluated true when I tested it.

Comment: @steveha thanks for your feedback. I agree. But I would like it to keep simple unless OP asks for. He has mentioned *numbers* only in his file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using only AWK, reading only one line at a time from each input file.

```
BEGIN {
    if (ARGC != 3)
    {
        print "Usage: this_program <file1> <file2>"
        exit(1)
    }

    c = 0
    for (;;)
    {
        result = getline < ARGV[1]
        if (1 != result)
            break
        n1 = $1 + 0

        result = getline < ARGV[2]
        if (1 != result)
            break
        n2 = $1 + 0
        if (n1 > n2)
            ++c;
    }
    print c
}
```

P.S. I'm a fan of Python and for fun I also solved this in Python.

```
import sys

if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    import itertools
    zip = itertools.izip

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f1, open(sys.argv[2]) as f2:
    print(sum(float(x) > float(y) for x, y in zip(f1, f2)))
```

Notes:

- `zip()` pairs values read from two sources.  `zip(f1, f2)` pairs a line read from each of the two input files.
- I made this use `itertools.izip()` when you run it on Python 2.x, so it will handle one line at a time.  The built-in `zip()` in Python 2 reads all the data at once and builds a list.
- The error checking isn't obvious but it is there.  If an input doesn't work as a `float` value, you will get an exception; if the user doesn't specify at least two input files, you will get an exception.
- This is using a slightly sleazy trick: `sum()` will treat a Boolean `True` value as a 1, and a Boolean `False` value as a 0.  Thus this gets a count of all the lines for which the `>` comparison is true.